# Lebesgue measure of a set and its closure

Tags: measure-theory

Is it true that for any $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ then the Lebesgue measure

$$m(A)=m(\overline{A})$$ And why?

where $\overline{A}$ denotes the closure of the set.

Comment: I assume you mean $A\subset\mathbb{R}$, not $A\in\mathbb{R}$, right?

Comment: yes, that was a typo

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider $A=\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: if $A=\mathbb{Q}$ then $m(\mathbb{Q})=0$ as $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable and $\overline{A}=\overline{Q}=\mathbb{R}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ but what is $m(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: I forgot to add that we are dealing with the natural topology

Comment: @StefanHansen ah you are right , then we must have $m(\mathbb{R})=\infty$ right? so the statement above is clearly false

Answer (score 1):

Let $r_n,n\in\mathbb N$ be an enumeration of the rational numbers. For $t\gt 0$, define 
$$S_t:=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}(r_n-t2^{-n}, r_n+t2^{-n}).$$
Since $\lambda(S_t\Delta S_u)\leqslant |t-u|$, the map $t\in\mathbb{R}_{\geqslant 0}\mapsto \lambda(S_t)\in\mathbb{R}_{\geqslant 0}$ (usual topology) is continuous. Hence for all $b\geqslant a\geqslant 0$, we can find a Borel measurable $B_{a,b}$ for which $\lambda(\overline{B_{a,b}})=a$ and $\lambda(B_{a,b})=b$ (intersect a $S_t$ with $[0,b]$).

Hence there is no link between the measure of a Borel measurable set and those of its closure.

Comment: If you say that the map $t\mapsto S_t$ is continuous, what is the codomain and what is the topology on the codomain? (Nevertheless, asking about finding a set fulfilling $\lambda(\overline{B_{a,b}})=a$ and $\lambda(B_{a,b})=b$ for any reasonable choice of $a$ and $b$ is a very nice generalization of the original question.)

Comment: I've edited (I meant the topology induced by the absolute value).

Comment: I am probably missing something. $S_t$ is a set, not a real number. Did you mean $t\mapsto \lambda(S_t)$?

Comment: But $S_t$ is a set, not a number. Surely you mean $S_t=\lambda\left( \bigcup \ldots \right)$?

Comment: Yes, I meant the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: thank you. I do have one question more. If we assume that for example A is an interval of the form $[a,b], (a,b], [a,b)$ then I think the construction above should work. What is your opinion?